# dismiss a tabbed view controller from a seperate modaled to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, I have a tab bar view controller, however at some point I need to manually segue to a viewcontroller that is not attached to the tab-view controller. The segue works, but then it jumps back again to the previous view controller randomly after 1/2 a second to 3 seconds, not all the time, but often. Occasionally I see a message saying something along the lines of "cannot dismiss viewcontroller while another dismiss or presentation is already taking place" but I've double checked all my code and there are only three places that make the jump, none of which can be called simultaneously. What I need to know then, is how I go about dismissing the tab viewcontroller in the view did load method of the modaled to controller.   Swift explanations are no good to me thanks.  Also, not related to this question persay, but can anyone tell me what the sliding bar thing that looks like a UISlider and tracks the progress of a song is called?

Comment: Are you creating the segue programmatically, or is it defined in the storyboard? Could you show the code you are using to present that modal viewcontroller and maybe some code that could lead to the solution, and the exact content of that error?

Comment: ah, I solved this problem in the end, the issue was that I had a background thread updating UI components for the previous viewcontroller, this meant that it had issues switching, after I changed from a background thread to a NSNotification the problem solved itself, mostly.

Comment: Ouch. UI updates should *always* be executed on the main thread. Period.

Comment: Yes, I've learnt my lesson. Been building an iOS 6 music app replica with coverflow and stuff, almost done it now but I was using the background thread to update the song title of now playing when I should have been using the notification system.